# Why does threading increase time (reduce performance) in this example?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

This code:

```
  object obj = new object { };
  Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
  watch.Start();
  for (int i = 0; i < 90000; i++)
  {
      new Thread(() =>
      {
          lock (obj)
          {
              string file = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(saeed);
              File.AppendAllText(string.Format(@"c:\Temp\{0}.txt", i), file);
          }
      }).Start();
  }
  watch.Stop();
```

runs in like 15 minutes, while this code:

```
  Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
  watch.Start();
  for (int i = 0; i < 90000; i++)
  {
      {
          string file = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(saeed);
          File.AppendAllText(string.Format(@"c:\Temp\{0}.txt", i), file);
      }
  }
  watch.Stop();
```

runs in like 45 seconds. Why is the first application so much slower while it's threaded? Isn't it true that using threads is a technique for improving performance of an application?

**Update:** Even by using closure concepts and referencing a middle-variable instead of `i` in my thread instead of using lock, which makes threads really async, still creating those files takes more than 5 minutes.

```
  Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
  watch.Start();
  for (int i = 0; i < 90000; i++)
  {
      var x = i;
      new Thread(() =>
      {
          string file = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(saeed);
          File.AppendAllText(string.Format(@"c:\Temp\{0}.txt", i), file);
      }).Start();
  }
  watch.Stop();
```

Comment: There is no point in multithreading if you add a huge `lock` block...

Comment: because you create new thread on every iteration

Comment: You're spinning up new threads each time.. and each thread has the same sync. You may as well have written a normal for loop with a couple more zero's on the end. The CPU is spinning for ages waiting for your lock to be released.

Comment: By removing lock, you end up in exceptions.

Comment: How many cores has your machine got?

Comment: It is hugely dangerous to just flat out consider Threads as a "technique for improving performance of an application".

Comment: You spawn 90000 threads (who share a critical section) on a normal PC and you expect it to go faster? :-/

Comment: Get rid of the lock, then replace your for with `Enumerable.Range(0,90000).AsParallel().ForAll( i=> { Contents of task});`

Comment: BTW, what is the question here? Obviously, taking 90000 locks on a single object is bad, so what is left to answer?

Comment: remember a multi-threaded code may be slower then single threaded code because of thread-context-switch  time involve

Comment: Parallel code can kill performance if not design correctly 90000 locks on single object shows bad design @PanagiotisKanavos is correct

Comment: Side note - in your edit, you are still using "i" instead of "x" inside the thread.

Comment: "Isn't this true that using threads is a technique for improving performance of an application?" - no, using threads correctly may improve performance in specific scenarios.

Comment: @BobVale for values of "Contents of task" that doesn't include saturating the filesystem :)

Comment: @JesseC.Slicer That's a different issue, there might be a requirement for 90000 files. Only took 20 secs on my machine so it's not that bad.

Comment: It's still taking 5 minutes because you are still creating 90000 threads.  Use of the Task Parallel Library or a ThreadPool will reduce the overhead by limiting the number of created threads based on the system capabilities and reusing already finished threads rather than needing to fire up new ones

Comment: I haven't seen it mentioned here yet, but it's important to note that the concept of performance gains via multithreading require using a resource that can perform more work in parallel than it can serially. Disk I/O is typically *not* that kind of resource. Usually, multithreading improves performance by allowing you to use multiple CPU cores. It would only help in a disk I/O case if you had multiple disks that could divide and share the work.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1) you are currently creating 90000 threads, which is not efficient at all. Don't create every time a thread, use a thread pool instead, so you reuse threads that are already created. Remember creating a thread takes some time and memory.

2) you are locking the whole code block with `lock`, which means each thread is blocked until another thread completed its work. So you basically are defeating the whole purpose of multi-threading here.

3) Disk I/O doesn't work well with multi-threading for complex hardware-related reasons (buffers....etc.). Generally it's not a good idea to multi-thread this part of code.

---

About comments concerning disk I/O and multi-threading : that's quite complicated actually.

For magnetic disks, the disk arm has to move in order to read/write bytes on the good sector/cylinder/track. If you write 2 different files at the same time (case of two threads, each writing a different file), depending on the physical file location on disk, you may ask your disk arm to **switch from one physical location to another very quickly**, which destroys performances. Writing multiple disk sectors for the first file on one physical location, **then** moving the disk arm to another location, **then** writing some disks sectors for the second file would be much more efficient. You can see this effect when you compare the time to copy two files at the same time vs copying one file, then the other.

So for this very basic example, performance gain/loss depends on:

- hardware itself. There is no disk arm with SSDs, so file access is way more faster
- physical file location
- file fragmentation
- bufferization. The [disk buffer system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer) helps reading consecutive blocks, which could not be of any help in case you have to move the arm to another location.

My humble advice: try to avoid multiple reads/writes in multiple threads if performances is your primary goal.

Comment: #3 is not an absolute. In fact, processing multiple files in parallel is a common (and efficient) trick for quick-and-dirty parallelism from the command line. E.g. using xargs in Linux to execute the same command for multiple files

Comment: Depends on the data, if you need to load 500kb from 500 files and do heavy CPU bound processing then yes it would help, otherwise if its 500MB and just moving data around then it likely won't help so much

Comment: Obviously, we are talking about the 500 files here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're absolutely right, it's not always true. But it depends on so much factors (magnetic disks vs SSD, file fragmentation, size of written blocks...) that it's hard to expect a performance gain and should be avoided if possible (IMHO) except if you really know what you're doing and what will be the impact on I/O of multi-threading

Comment: It's not that disk IO doesn't work well with multithreading - actually, multiple threads can be useful when doing blocking IO in one thread while doing stuff in the others, or taking turns for IO. The point is that you typically don't have any gain in performance writing to the same disc from multiple threads at top speed, because *it's just one disc* and it's way slower than the processor anyway, so multithreading does not affect the real bottleneck here. "buffers" have little to do with all this (actually, they help increase the performance).

Comment: You miss the point. It is ALREADY used effectivelly. Just google for `xargs parallel`. Most single-threded programs never process at top speed or even half-speed. You can easily increase performance by running them in parallel until you max your IO

Comment: See edited question, I added some clarifications about point @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: In a situation where for example you have a repeated sequence of 1/2 second CPU followed by 1 second of I/O, it makes sense to multi-thread to keep I/O saturated. You would only need a couple of threads in that case. Accordingly, rule #3 is indeed not absolute.

Answer (score 19):

Threading can speedup your code by giving you more execution engines.  But you are exploring very different resource limits in the first snippet.

The first one is the ability of the machine to commit 90 *gigabytes* of memory.  The space required for the stacks of the threads.  That takes a while, your harddisk if probably furiously working to create the backup store for that much memory.  .NET is a bit unusual in that it commits the stack space for a thread, it provides an execution guarantee.  Something you can turn off btw, the `<disableCommitThreadStack>` element in the app.exe.config file ought to have a very noticeable effect.

The second resource limit you are exploring is the ability of the file system to modify that many files concurrently.  It will be greatly hampered by the first limitation, you are stealing lots of RAM away from the file system cache.  When it runs out of space, you are seeing the effect of these threads all trying to commandeer the disk write head.  Forcing it to zip back and forth between the file clusters.  Disk seeks are **very** slow, by far the slowest operation on a disk.  It is a mechanical operation, the drive head arm needs to physically move, something that takes many milliseconds.  The hard page faults your code is very likely to generate makes it a lot worse as well.

The *lock* in your threaded code will reduce this thrashing but won't eliminate it.  With the large memory demand, your program is liable to generate a great many deal of page faults.  Worse case is on every thread context switch.  The thread will be blocked while the disk performs a seek + read to satisfy the page-in request.

Well, kudos to Windows by letting you do this and not falling over.  But clearly this was a bad idea.  Use at most a *few* threads.  Or just one if the writes are going to saturate the file system cache anyway so you'll avoid the seek penalty.

Comment: I always manage to learn something from your posts Hans. Thanks.

Comment: In the original code presented in the question, the lock prevents the code from working concurrently. 90000 threads are created, all of them at the gate except one running the code. I would expect that most of the time is spent waiting for thread management.

Answer (score 7):

I would note that most answers haven't read the example the code.  This is not about spawning a bunch of threads and writing to disk, this is about spawning a bunch of threads, doing some work *new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(saeed);* and **then** writing to disk!

This is important to note, because the longer that work takes the more benefit simple threading provides by making sure the disk isn't idling while computation takes place.

---

The long and short of it is because you wrote some simplistic code, as others have explained:

1. You are creating 90,000 threads - this is expensive and
   unnecessary!
2. You are locking all the work, making this single threaded!

   1. Yes without the lock you get an exception... that doesn't magically make the lock a good idea from a performance idea - it just means you've got erroneous code.

A quick and easy way to get into threading - that's slightly less dangerous (though you can still stuff it up) is to use the Task Parallel Library.  For example:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication15
{
    class Program
    {
        const int FILE_COUNT = 9000;
        const int DATA_LENGTH = 100;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(@"c:\Temp\")) Directory.Delete(@"c:\Temp\", true);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\Temp\");

            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < FILE_COUNT; i++)
            {
                string data = new string(i.ToString()[0], DATA_LENGTH);
                File.AppendAllText(string.Format(@"c:\Temp\{0}.txt", i), data);
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Wrote 90,000 files single-threaded in {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Directory.Delete(@"c:\Temp\", true);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"c:\Temp\");

            watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Parallel.For(0, FILE_COUNT, i =>
            {
                string data = new string(i.ToString()[0], DATA_LENGTH);
                File.AppendAllText(string.Format(@"c:\Temp\{0}.txt", i), data);
            });
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Wrote 90,000 files multi-threaded in {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

The single threaded version runs in about 8.1 seconds, and the multi-threaded version runs in about 3.8 seconds.  Note that my test values are different than yours.

While the TPL's default settings aren't always optimised for the scenario you're working on, they provide a much better basis than running 90,000 threads!  You'll also note that in this case I don't have to do any locking nor do I have to handle the closure - because the API presented already handles that for me.

Comment: How will TPL tasks (which use the threadpool anyway) help here?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead TPL provides multithreading, which in my test did improve performance.  TPL also provides a bunch of built in features, like thread-pooling, that significantly improve performance over the OP's attempts.

Comment: Without testing it I'm having a hard time believing the performance increase all that significant. Yes the pooling will result in < 90k threads, but the locking alone with the threadpool thread cap would surely continue to bog this down. All speculation I guess though.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I doubled my performance in the test code, reread my answer.

Comment: TPL takes care of using a reasonable number of threads. In case of CPU bound tasks, it would just use as many threads as there are cores.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is two fold

1. Creating a Thread is `expensive` in that it takes a non-trivial amount of time to do.
2. You are locking on `obj`, this actually ensures only a single thread can run at a time in this example, so you're not actually running in a multi-threaded way.

Comment: If you remove the lock statement, Exceptions would be fired. Try it.

Comment: Maybe he needs different files.

Comment: He probably gets exceptions because he has no control over the value of i at the moment the started threads use it to generate the filename and he may very well end up with threads accessing the same file at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Because a thread is made inside the for loop with the lock. So the threads are performed one by one and not simultaneously like in the second example.

Comment: If you remove the `lock` statement, Exceptions would be fired. Try it.

Comment: Besides the lock, creating 90K threads is not exactly easy on the system.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati What exceptions?

Comment: I am sorry I cannot try it on a computer now ... but it might be good to show the Exception you get to help you further.

Comment: The process cannot access the file 'c:\Temp\66.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati, That shouldn't happen, the code is using unique file names for each file in the loop have you copied the OP code correctly?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati, oh actually it could be a closure problem.  Remove lock and use `var x = i` before creating the task/thread and reference x instead of i inside the task

Comment: @Saeed Neamati, its because of the way you use closure in your example. You cant use it like that when multithreading. Value of `i` changes constantly and there is no guarantee, that when you access `i` in your thread its value will be the same as it was, when this thread was created. You should remove `lock` and copy `i` value to local varibale on every iteration, an then use this local variable in your threads, instead of using `i`.